# Using EXEC() to re-create stored procedure doesn't find errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm checking the validity of existing stored procedures, by obtaining their definition and running the ALTER statement on them.

The problem I have is that any stored procedure which doesn't compile (because a dependency has gone) isn't being flagged as such.

If I try to run the same ALTER command in SSMS I do get the error message.
EDIT: No, I don't....

```
DECLARE @def nvarchar(MAX)
BEGIN TRY
    -- refresh the stored procedure
    SELECT @def = REPLACE(definition,'CREATE PROCEDURE ','ALTER PROCEDURE ')
      FROM sys.sql_modules
     WHERE ... -- selecting/limiting clause

    EXEC (@def);

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Validation failed : ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

What do I have to do to trap the non-compile error? Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting when you ALTER a proc exactly? You probably shouldn't ever see an issue because SQL Server does deferred name resolution (at least for tables) when creating procs.

Comment: Oops!! My mistake - SSMS will compile stored procs with missing dependencies - it only highlights the missing items with a red squiggle...

Comment: OK, voting to close this now as it's not reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server stored procedures use [deferred name resolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx):

> When a stored procedure is created, the statements in the procedure are parsed for syntactical accuracy. If a syntactical error is encountered in the procedure definition, an error is returned and the stored procedure is not created. If the statements are syntactically correct, the text of the stored procedure is stored in the `sys.sql_modules` catalog view.
>
> When a stored procedure is executed for the first time, the query processor reads the text of the stored procedure from the `sys.sql_modules` catalog view and checks that the names of the objects used by the procedure are present. This process is called deferred name resolution because table objects referenced by the stored procedure need not exist when the stored procedure is created, but only when it is executed.

So the behavior you observe is intentional. What you need is to find out what procedures depend on your missing tables. For this, see [View the Dependencies of a Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345404.aspx) and the proper answer depends on your SQL Server version. SQL Server 2016 is somehow better at tracking this information and offers better views. Before that the process was notoriously difficult unreliable, read [Keeping sysdepends up to date in SQL Server 2008](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 0):

Forget this - barking up the wrong tree ;-((

The stored proc will compile OK even if its dependencies have gone.
The editor in SSMS highlights the missing items, but doesn't stop the ALTER statement from working.

This query will identify all stored procs with missing dependencies:

```
-- table variable to store procedure names
DECLARE @v TABLE (RecID INT IDENTITY(1,1), spname sysname)

-- retrieve the list of stored procedures
INSERT INTO @v(spname)
    SELECT 
        '[' + s.[name] + '].[' + sp.name + ']'
    FROM sys.procedures sp
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = sp.schema_id
    WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0
      AND sp.name like 'Get%'

-- counter variables
DECLARE @cnt INT, @Tot INT
SELECT @cnt = 1
SELECT @Tot = COUNT(*) FROM @v

DECLARE @spname sysname
DECLARE @ref nvarchar(MAX)

-- start the loop
WHILE @Cnt <= @Tot BEGIN
    SELECT @spname = spname
        FROM @v
        WHERE RecID = @Cnt

    BEGIN

        SELECT @ref = referenced_entity_name
          FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (@spname, 'OBJECT')
         WHERE referenced_id IS NULL;

    END
    SET @Cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```